# Streaming video from nsurlsession to avplayer?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, nsurlsession

I have a class handling all remote downloads for media in my app. I am creating nsurlsessions and using nsurlsessiondownloaddelegate for handling the completion and progress. Is there a way to hook this up to avplayeritem in order to begin downloading a video but if it is requested before its complete it starts streaming into a avplayer?

Comment: You should first take a look at Apple's sample code for doing this same thing, and then remember the following: if you app downloads or needs to download a video or media file that exceeds ~5mb then YOU MUST use HTTP streaming services, this is all native IOS stuff that Apple has set up for you. I'll like the sample project here in a second

Comment: Tyler, here's the sample code, and it does basically exactly what you need and plays video from both downloaded files and from stream: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVFoundationQueuePlayer-iOS/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Awesome I'll check that out thank you!